# How to modify a prop before constructor is called?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to pass a class of an object as a prop, and then instantiate it, before the constructor is called, e.g.

```
export class Knight implements AbstractCharacter {
  public name = "Knight";
  public hp = 500;
  public damage = 1000;
}
```

React Component:

```
export default class CharacterView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.props.character = new props.character() // this isn't allowed
     }
    render() {
       return(
            <Text>
                  HP: {"" + this.props.character.hp}, Dmg: {this.props.character.damage}
            </Text>
     }
```

Called:

```
 <CharacterView character = {Knight} />   // won't work
 <CharacterView character = {new Knight()} /> // Would work, but it doesn't follow DRY principle. Also I would want to have multiple instances of Knight()
```

To do this in python I would use the `__new__` constructor, rather than the `__init__`. Is there something similar in JS, where you can intercept the constructor?

Comment: You should probably just use `state` for this

Comment: Would it be possible to do it in props? I'd rather not muddy my redux with this component

Comment: @AH What do you expect to happen when the character prop is changed (from the outside)?

Comment: I only want to add the character to a list of characters (i.e. a team), so if a user wants to have 2 knights, they won't share the same HP .

Comment: According React-Native standards( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props ) props can not be modify, its always single for that component , if You want to modify the value for that component, Use State or any variable.
Assign the value in state or variable .